# How to react to getting focus from another application?

Tags: java, events, focus, javafx-8

My JavaFX 8 application has to `doStuff()` when it gets focused. That's pretty simple:

```
primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, wasFocused, nowFocused) -> {
    doStuff();
});
```

However, when I display a dialog and user closes it, `doStuff()` fires. I want it to fire only when user switches from another app to mine, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> from a browser.

In other words, I want to `doStuff()` iff other app's window loses focus and my app's window gets focus.

Is it possible?

*Edit:* Answers posted by [FibreFoX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34496072/1937994) and [Appelemac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34484161/1937994) require explicitly performing additional step before showing a dialog. This solution is far from perfect, because I (or any developer, in general) have to remember about this step before showing a dialog. Forgetting about it will introduce hard to find bugs.

Extending `Dialog` to do it automatically isn't an option, because I want to use built-in dialogs that already extend original `Dialog`.

That's pretty basic feature, I'd be surprised if there's no easy way to achieve this in JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a listener to your Dialog, which then allows you to not doStuff() if the Dialog was just closed/lost focus.

Easiest way I can think of is setting an Instant (with Instant.now) when the dialog is closed, and if the application regains focus, create another Instant, and check whether the `Duration.between(instantLostFocusDialog, instantGainedFocusApp).getSeconds()` exceeds 1 (or add `getNano()` to that to be more specific). Only then would you `doStuff()`

Comment: Doing that for every single dialog doesn't sound like fun. I hope there's a way to handle it automatically.

Comment: hmmm, I'd suggest creating a (Array)List of Instant for the dialogs, creating a small sub-class for the listeners, and implement the adding of an Instant to that List, then checking for every Instant. Not very efficient, but I think it'd work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global boolean when opening such dialogs, and only when that global switch is true/false/whatever-you-choose then you could react on that state-switch.

```
public class GlobalDialogMemory{
    public static boolean dialogShown = false;
}
```

When using CDI you could inject the application-scoped current instance (but you should use getter/setter and non-static booleans instead ;)